# Keeping environments organized when using pyenv, pip, and Homebrew

Tags: pip, homebrew, pyenv

My goal is pretty simple: to do a pip install of some software.

I already use pyenv and Homebrew, but haven't much lately. I don't remember all the details as clearly now. And it's also likely my understanding is not as complete as I previously believed.

Today I realized that I don't understand the encapsulation hierarchy or interplay between the three:

**Homebrew** / **pyenv** / **pip**

I thought doing `brew install` or `pip install` would install the software inside of my current `pyenv` environment. But as I'm looking at tutorials, I realize that `pyenv` itself was installed by means of `brew install`, so clearly there are gaps in my understanding of the structure of this whole organizational system.

Can somebody please ELI5, maybe with a visual sketch (I learn best visually), how this is all supposed to be structured in order to work correctly? I want to keep the environments separated and functioning correctly.

Sorry if this is pretty basic for some people, but I want to be sure I finally understand rather than fumbling forward on assumption, as I add more and more software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *[homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/)* - is a package manager (basically for macOS, because it didn't have one, so some smart people filled that void) there is also a version for linux, called *linuxbrew*. It is needed to install\remove programs in a automated and consistent manner.
- *[pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)* is a program, helper tool you name it. Which was designed to help manage multiple *python* installations on the same computer. There are multiple options to install *pyenv*, one of them is via *homebrew*.
- *[pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/)* is a package installer for python. It is being used by python to install python packages. Guess what, *pip* is a python module by itself. You can invoke it like this `python -m pip`

I think what you meant by *pyenv* is actually a *[venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)* another python module, that allows to install *pip* packages locally. So you'll be able to have multiple versions of same package installed in different projects on same computer.

**Bottomline**

*homebrew* is for installing any piece of software that exists in their repos.

*pyenv* is a tool to manage python installations.

*pip* manages python packages. It is usually bundled with python installation. BTW there are alternatives to pip, one of them is *[poetry](https://python-poetry.org/)*